# Using constexpr in class constructor with a fixed length array but declared at instantiation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm looking to instantiate a class with a constant member `animalList` that is (or points to) an array of another type `Animal`. My goal is to have all of these created and evaluated at compile time, which is why I'm using const and constexpr.

I think a pointer to a vector would work in this situation, but there is so much data that the extra overhead vectors would take up is not worth it, as far as I know. Plus, I don't need arrays to be of variable length after declaration. They will be fixed and constant, but they will be different for every class instance.

So having fixed-length arrays would make the most sense, but each instance will have a different length, and the compiler doesn't allow arrays to be declared without a fixed length specified in the class definition. My thought process was that if `animalList` could not be defined without a length, at least I would be able to specify a pointer to a fixed-length array of an unknown length.

In my head this would work:

```cpp
class Animal {
  // ...
};

class Continent {
  public:
    const Animal[]* animalList; // animalList is of type pointer to array of animals
    constexpr Continent(Animal[]* animalsOnContinent) : animalList(animalsOnContinent) {}
};
```

But Animal[]* is not a valid type

Comment: what extra overhead of `std::vector` do you refer to? It has some extra members compared to `std::array` but the more data or elements you have the lesser important gets that additional bytes

Comment: There are (as far as I know) only five continents. So that's five vectors and presumably 1000s of animals. So where's the overhead? Any overhead is **per vector**, it does not depend on the number of items in the vector.

Comment: My app actually has nothing to do with continents or animals. I tried to simplify the question to not include unnecessary stuff related to what I'm doing - but I digress - I'm talking about thousands of classes. Each class has an array of 5-10 members each. These will be generated programmatically (actually a big node application generating a C library). Binary size is really important as this will be WASM. This is why the difference between a 7-byte-long fixed array taking up ~8 bytes for example will be double than a 7-byte-long vector taking up ~14 bytes when multiplied thousandsfold

Comment: Is it not possible to have a pointer to a place in memory that is an integer L followed by L amount of bytes of Animal object references? Isn't that exactly how arrays work? An integer length followed by size of element * L bytes?

Comment: use a `std::vector` and call it a day. I dont understand what overhead you are afraid of

Comment: @Pete What you're trying to do is possible in C++20. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n5G9reW79) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122392/12002570) given below.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: No need for std::vector, a std::array is fine and comes without the overhead. User asks for full compile time solution!

Comment: @Klaus OP wants different instances of `Continent` to have differnt number of `Animal`s in an array. Their desire to use a fixed size array is what started their problems. Using a `std::vector` is the simple solution here

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number OP writes: "Plus, I don't need arrays to be of variable length after declaration. They will be fixed and constant, but they will be different for every class instance." For my point of view, this can't be done with a non templated type. So I assume a template instance for each Continent is a solution.

Comment: @Klause in your answer every continent is of a different type. I doubt that thats what OP wants

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Might be :-) Let him decide. The requirement "full compile time constant" vs. "single typed solution" is simply impossible as we know.

Comment: @Klaus it is possible, but unecessarily compilcated. Also, a `std::vector` can be filled at compile time too. I dont understand what OP wants because the reasons for not using `std::vector` are unclear to me

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number My understanding is, that he wants to avoid the overhead of a dynamic array which needs to allocate heap. A constexpr version is available from c++20 which may be a solution. But no need to have further discussions. I see the both options. For my experience a vector is not always perfect, maybe for bare metal uCs, the overhead is significant. As for small embedded systems, the std::array solution as presented by me fits much better. But on a full featured PC it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is possible from C++20 onwards.

But first things first, `const Animal[]* animalList;` is not valid C++ syntax. The correct syntax for declaring `animalList` as a pointer to an array of unknown bound with elements of type `Animal` would be `Animal (*animalList)[];` as shown below.

##### C++20

With C++ 20 pointer/references to array of unknown bound can point/refer to regular arrays(pointer to array of known bound). So with C++20 the following is valid:

```
class Animal {
  // ...
};

class Continent {
  public:
    Animal (*animalList)[]; // animalList is of type pointer to array of animals
    Continent(Animal (*ptr)[]): animalList(ptr)
    {
        
    }
   
};
int main()
{
    Animal a[5]{};
    Continent c(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n5G9reW79)

You can do the same with references:

```
class Animal {
  // ...
};

class Continent {
  public:
    Animal (&animalList)[]; // animalList is of type pointer to array of animals
    Continent(Animal (&ptr)[]): animalList(ptr)
    {
        
    }
   
};
int main()
{
    Animal a[5]{};
    Continent c(a);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nc9hK9Wr5)

---

You can also use `std::vector` if you want the container to be flexible like we can change its size at runtime. Additionally, using `std::array` instead of built in array is also an option for avoiding things like *array to pointer decay* that happens implicitly with built in arrays.

Comment: Are you taking into consideration that the lengths of each instantiation is known at compile time? Example, I know there are 5 animals in Africa, 7 in America, etc. Can't the class member just be a pointer to a place in address to an array of a fixed length? IE, a pointer to an address which is an integer (array length) followed by a series in memory of addresses (which is what an array is in essence)? I don't understand how this would be impossible in low level language like C++

Comment: @Pete With C++20 we can. See my updated answer where i've given a solution for C++20 using pointers and reference.